# i've got error when use Inner join with 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

hello i have search too many and i checked my query word by word but i can't fix this error

my query :

```
SELECT  color_table.color, size_table.size, size_table.length, size_table.sum, image_table.image_url, manto_table.name, manto_table.description, manto_table.price_sale, manto_table.price_coop,
 manto_table.price_single FROM size_table INNER JOIN
                         color_table ON size_table.color_id = color_table.id INNER JOIN
                         manto_table INNER JOIN
                         image_table ON manto_table.id = image_table.manto_id ON size_table.manto_id = manto_table.id;
```

error :

> Type: PDOException
>   Code: 42000
>   Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON size_table.manto_id = manto_table.id' at line 5

Comment: INNER JOIN  manto_table **ON** missing

Comment: join before last "on" forget?

Comment: The message seems self explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT color_table.color, 
       size_table.size, 
       size_table.length, 
       size_table.sum, 
       image_table.image_url, 
       manto_table.NAME, 
       manto_table.description, 
       manto_table.price_sale, 
       manto_table.price_coop, 
       manto_table.price_single 
FROM   size_table 
       LEFT JOIN color_table AS color_table
               ON size_table.color_id = color_table.id 
       LEFT JOIN manto_table  AS manto_table
               ON manto_table.id = image_table.manto_id 
       LEFT JOIN image_table  AS image_table
               ON size_table.manto_id = manto_table.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

modify it like this:

```
SELECT  color_table.color, size_table.size, size_table.length, size_table.sum, image_table.image_url, manto_table.name, manto_table.description, manto_table.price_sale, manto_table.price_coop,
 manto_table.price_single
 FROM size_table 
 INNER JOIN color_table ON size_table.color_id = color_table.id 
 INNER JOIN manto_table ON manto_table.id = image_table.manto_id 
 INNER JOIN image_table ON size_table.manto_id = manto_table.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-organize your sentence to:

```
    SELECT  color_table.color, size_table.size, size_table.length, size_table.sum, image_table.image_url, 
        manto_table.name, manto_table.description, manto_table.price_sale, manto_table.price_coop, manto_table.price_single 
 FROM size_table 
     INNER JOIN manto_table ON size_table.manto_id = manto_table.id
     INNER JOIN image_table ON manto_table.id = image_table.manto_id 
     INNER JOIN color_table ON size_table.color_id = color_table.id ;
```